# Taking .exe modules Import Table ordinal and finding the import modules function name?

Tags: c++, c, api, winapi, portable-executable

So I load up paltalk.exe as a argument into my c++ command line program and I get this output:

```
 [Walk_Imports]: Imported DLL [0] WSOCK32.dll 
--------------------------------------------------
 [Import_By_Ordinal]: address: 80000016 
 [Import_By_Ordinal]: address: 80000003 
 [Import_By_Ordinal]: address: 80000073 
 [Import_By_Ordinal]: address: 80000017 
 [Import_By_Ordinal]: address: 80000015 
 [Import_By_Ordinal]: address: 8000000B 
 [Import_By_Ordinal]: address: 80000014 
 [Import_By_Ordinal]: address: 8000000E 
 [Import_By_Ordinal]: address: 8000000A 
 [Import_By_Ordinal]: address: 80000034 
 [Import_By_Ordinal]: address: 80000011 
 [Import_By_Ordinal]: address: 80000013 
 [Import_By_Ordinal]: address: 80000010 
 [Import_By_Ordinal]: address: 80000009 
 [Import_By_Ordinal]: address: 80000002 
 [Import_By_Ordinal]: address: 80000008 
 [Import_By_Ordinal]: address: 8000006F 
 [Import_By_Ordinal]: address: 80000097 
 [Import_By_Ordinal]: address: 80000012 
 [Import_By_Ordinal]: address: 80000004 
 [Import_By_Ordinal]: address: 8000000F 
 [Import_By_Ordinal]: address: 8000000C 

 22 functions imported (22 ordinal)
```

Paltalk imports the wsock32.dll ok great news. I walk its imports and i see there all ordinal names.

How do I take these import ordinal names and with c or c++ load the wsock32.dll and walk its export table to match the ordinal name with the corresponding function name?

I hope this is enough information to get my question across. If not I can add more information.

Thanks

Comment: The point of exporting by ordinal is to **not** provide a function name.

Answer (score 1):

By such a broad question about the Portable Executable infrastructure, take a look at Matt Pietrek http://www.wheaty.net and how he implemented the retrieval of such details in PEDUMP (code provided).